# Host Mac OS X package (.mpkg) or Bundle (.bundle) on IIS

Tags: macos, iis, hosting

long story short: I have an installer for Mac OS X in package format (.mpkg) and I need to host it in IIS so that people can download it, I can't use Apache, and IIS consider .mpkg or .bundle to be directories.

Besides using a dmg or a zip, how can I let IIS allow Mac users to download the .mpkg file directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A disk image (dmg) or zip file are your only options -- Mac OS X bundles *are* directories.  The only difference is that, because of their extension, certain parts of the OS such as the the Finder treat them as single files.  This is true of other kinds of bundles too: RTFD files (rich text with pictures) and applications.